# Зачем учить Python, что можно с ним создать?

Tags: php, python, веб-программирование

Зачем учить Python, да, он самый удобный и читабельный , но зачем ? Для веб-девелопмента есть варианты по-популярней и по эффектней ( php, Javascript ). Можно использовать для создания скриптов ( Maya, blender и т. д. ). А для чего еще можно использовать? Не считая создания серверов. В каких сферах его можно задействовать не как прикладной язык, а как основной ?

Comment: Что значит "не как прикладной язык, а как основной"?

Comment: типо как Objective-C для iOS, как С/С++ для Windows, так как PHP для Facebook

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Веб-разработка (да как вообще можно сравнивать python и php?!)
- Прочие не-веб интернет-сервисы (я себе записывалку интернет-радио с подсчитывалкой треков делал)
- Различные статистические расчёты (особенно с numpy и cython)
- прототипирование (например, драйвер для USB-принтеров в KolibriOS изначально тестировался под линуксом на питоне)
- Небольшие скрипты для личного (и не очень) использования (типа как продвинутый аналог bash)
- Да и десктоп-приложения некоторые делают (Gajim, установщик Ubuntu и пр.)

Answer (score 3):

Часто используют для анализа данных и machine learning

- NumPy
- pandas
- NumPy
- SciPy
- mlpy
- scikit-learn

Написаны на питоне:

- Sublime
- Youtube
- Instagram
- Pinterest
- [и другие проекты](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82:%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B8/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F,_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_Python)

Есть проблема с [GIL](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Interpreter_Lock)

Answer (score 0):

Например,  на нем написаны различные сервисы ([SMS Firewall](http://www.anam.com/sms-firewall/) и т.п.) операторов мобильной связи.